# Позиционирование текста внутри пустого блока

Tags: html, css, css3

Хотелось бы увидеть толковый ответ на вопрос о позиционировании текста в пустом блоке как на картинке ниже. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задачу я собственно решил списком, поместив внутрь каждого элемента ссылку с текстом. Нужные размеры для блока задавались путём полей для ссылки. Обращаю Ваше внимание на то, что блоки должны быть кликабельные по всей ширине/высоте.

Собственно смущает задание размеров с помощью полей. Свой код приведу ниже.

```css
.genres_stations {
  display: flex;
  height: 383px;
  width: 940px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

.genre {
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.genre a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: inherit;
  padding: 138px 0 18px;
  color: #2a333c;
}
```

```html
<ul class="genres_stations">
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Trending Top</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Rock</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">R n B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Alternative</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Country</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Pop</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Jazz</a>
  </li>
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">Reggae</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы так реализовал. Не думаю что нужны какие то комментарии

```css
.genres_stations {
  display: flex;
  height: 383px;
  width: 940px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

.genre {
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.genre a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="genres_stations">
  <li class="genre">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="" title="foto" />
      <span>Trending Top</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хм... Задумался над тем, чтобы перенести картинки в разметку. Вроде так даже лучше будет

Comment: Только мне непонятно почему в стилях для ссылки сначала ширина 100%, а потом наследование ширины родителя.

Comment: Я просто забыл убрать. )))

Comment: Ну и конечно пример то хороший, но сути вопроса он не меняет. Поля так и остались, а объяснения никакого.

Comment: Ты же просил как на картинке... Я тебе показал логику... А дальше сам... И что не понятно... ??

Comment: Хотелось именно понимания почему так, а не этак. Вариантов решения можно много накидать, а вот выбрать среди этих вариантов сложно, если недавно начал осваивать вёрстку.

Comment: Все зависит от ситуации. Я же, да и ни кто, кроме тебя, не могу знать, что у тя в голове? Все зависит от конечного результат.

Comment: Понимаешь, твой вопрос очень обширный...

Comment: Да, я это прекрасно понимаю. Спасибо за отзывчивость.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2):

Я вот так это сделал, вроде бы адаптивно

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  outline: 10px solid #fff;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 24px 6px;
}

p,
i.fa {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #999;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .items {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .item {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 40px 6px;
    margin: 6px;
  }
  p,
  i.fa {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .items {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .item {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 30px 6px;
    outline: 8px solid #fff;
  }
  p,
  i.fa {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-microchip"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```